# Linux password manager program

Tags: passwords, password-management

I' m looking for a Linux password manager, to manage my large number of passwords. I've always been using Keepass, but recently switched to Arch and you really feel this is not a native Linux application. It loads slow, and it has a Windows look oddly integrated in Linux. I'm looking for an alternative. I really like to be able to encrypt my passwords using an SSH key, instead of yet another password, and in addition to this quick retrieval is important (quick search for password and copying it to clipboard). That would be all of my needs.

What do you use? Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is actually a browser plugin, I have been quite happy with [LastPass](http://lastpass.com) for all my password needs.  It does encrypt with a password though, so it does not meet that requirement.  It does everything else quite well.  They do also have stand-alone apps that run in Linux as well as mobile apps and 2-factor authentication.  Though the mobile and 2-factor requires a paid subscription.

All of your devices/browsers are synced to storage in their system, which makes some people uneasy about storing all the passwords there, though they defend that they are unable to decrypt anyone's password contents.

Answer (score 2):

The v2 branch of KeePass runs on Mono, somewhat more integrated.

A native program called **KeePassX** also exists and is compatible with KeePass v1 databases.

Personally? I have a greppable `passwords.txt`.

---

Oh, also. You said "encrypt passwords with a SSH key". SSH keys aren't used for encryption, only for authentication and signing.

That does not mean, however, that you *cannot* use them for encryption, just that you *shouldn't*. But the private part of an OpenSSH key will be accepted by OpenSSL command-line tool and by pretty much everything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cpassman , it is compatible with linux and windows environments.
Plus everyone in the organization can use it for personal passwords and organization passwords .. each department can see the whole passwords that related to their work.

You can download and it is easy to install :)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/communitypasswo/files/1.8x/cpassman_1.82.zip/download?_test=goal

Answer (score 0):

More often than not [SuperGenPass](http://supergenpass.com/) is great for passwords. The original bookmark is dangerous to use but the extensions are great and the mobile page is also useful.

As for using SSH to encrypt passwords this was discussed in the following question:

> [Use ssh key to encrypt and decrypt a password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165042/use-ssh-key-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-password)